# Solr basic authentication without setting credentials for each request

Tags: solr, basic-authentication, solrj, solrcloud

Currently I am using SOLR basic authentication feature on my SOLR cloud using Solrj library. According to documentation and only way I found, the code looks like this -

```
SolrRequest<QueryResponse> req = new QueryRequest(solrQuery); 
req.setBasicAuthCredentials("admin", "foobar");
QueryResponse rsp = req.process(solrClient, liveStreamCollection);
documentList = rsp.getResults();
```

I am wondering if there is a way to avoid `setBasicAuthCredentials` for each request and perform it only once per session on `solrClient`?

### Edit

Above approach worked both for `SolrClient` and `SolrCloudClient` (both core and collection). To avoid passing basic credentials for each request, I tried to build and use a `HttpClient` like this.

```
AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope("192.168.x.x", 8983);
UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("admin", "foobar");
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(authScope, creds);
HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
builder.addInterceptorFirst(new PreemptiveAuthInterceptor());
builder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = builder.build();
solrClient = new HttpSolrClient("http://192.168.x.x:8983/solr/", httpClient);
```

And the `PreemptiveAuthInterceptor` class:

```
static class PreemptiveAuthInterceptor implements HttpRequestInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void process(final HttpRequest request, final HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
        AuthState authState = (AuthState) context.getAttribute(HttpClientContext.TARGET_AUTH_STATE);
        // If no auth scheme available yet, try to initialize it preemptively
        if (authState.getAuthScheme() == null) {
            CredentialsProvider credsProvider = (CredentialsProvider) 
                        context.getAttribute(HttpClientContext.CREDS_PROVIDER);
            HttpHost targetHost = (HttpHost) context.getAttribute(HttpCoreContext.HTTP_TARGET_HOST);
            AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope(targetHost.getHostName(), targetHost.getPort());
            Credentials creds = credsProvider.getCredentials(authScope);
            if(creds == null){

            }
            authState.update(new BasicScheme(), creds);
        }

    }
}
```

This worked for a single machine Solr core but I don't know how to use this with Solr cloud(passing Zookeeper hosts etc). Any idea?

Thanks in advance!